# java.lang.unsupportedclassversionerror akka/actor/Actor: unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a Java/Scala/Akka project that I am building in Jenkins. For it, I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.unsupportedclassversionerror akka/actor/Actor: unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I looked up the error and for instance here [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi), the cause is that an older version of Java is used instead of Java 8.

So I added to the Jenkins `configure` `JAVA_HOME=/my/path/to/jdk/1.8/exec`.

However, the error persists. So what could be the cause?

Comment: Have you checked what version you have set in your jenkins' job configuration? Have you cleaned your workspace?

Answer (score -1):

Please add JDK 8 in the Jenkins configuration and set the configured JDK in a job configuration. Nothing hard there.